# How do I configure eslint to ignore 2 space indent when using preceding commas in declaration sections

Tags: eslint

I've looked high and low for an eslint setting that will turn off the warning when I am aligning my parameters together vertically.  So if our tab spacing is 4 spaces, we want to indent the first item at 6 spaces (that is done manually), then align the following parameters at 4 spaces.  This keeps all the variables lined up.

Does anyone know the setting in eslint prevent it from complaining that `Project` variable is indented by 2 chars?

```
const {
      Project
    , Dimension
    , Task
    , View
    , Layout
    , User
    , Group
    , Organization
    , CustomField } = db.model;
```

[Visual Code shows `Project` as an eslint error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dt6xV.png)